# Getting Redirect_URI to work with Google Oauth in Codename one

Tags: oauth-2.0, codenameone

I am trying to get Google Oauth working with ios in CNO. I have it working fine with a web app, but I can't quite figure out how to have CNO know when to use which client ID or redirect_URI, etc. Below is my code that works fine. The CNO documentation is no help.

```java
Login gc = GoogleConnect.getInstance();
                gc.setClientId(web_client_ID);
                gc.setRedirectURI("https://google.com");
                gc.setClientSecret(client_secret);
                doLogin(gc, new GoogleData(), false)
```

I have a different Client ID for iOS, but where would I put that? How do I change my RedirectURI when I don't want for the OAuth to go to a website, but back to my app?

Answer (score 0):

The client ID is always the native login ID for the device. You can use the `isSimulator()` method to check if you're running in the simulator to use the web ID.

Comment: So when I actually deploy my app on iOS, what variables to I input into those fields? My understanding is that I would do `setClientId(ios_client_id)`, but what do I do for RedirectURI? Does it not matter? Or is it my ios URL scheme? I tried using that in the simulator but it gave me an error.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. It will flash for a second possibly and you will receive the login success event